# Compound query in parse cloud JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform

I'm trying to do a Parse.Query with multiple constraints, using OR and AND operations. For example, an operation like this:

```
(x1>2 OR x2<5) && (x3 equalTo 4) && (x4>7 OR x5<8)
```

Where the `x1`, `x2`, `x3` variables represent a query constraint over an specific field. I'm aware that I can do Parse.Query.or using two different queries as parameters, and then doing AND operations adding additional constraints to the result, like this:

```
var lotsOfWins = new Parse.Query("Player");
lotsOfWins.greaterThan(150);

var fewWins = new Parse.Query("Player");
fewWins.lessThan(5);

var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(lotsOfWins, fewWins);
```

But how can I make the operation described before if I have more than one "OR" operation? Is there a way to make the constraints directly in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the API documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_or) you can just pass in as many arguments as you like to `Parse.Query.or`.

Answer (score 0):

We want the query in disjunctive form, so:

```
(x1>2 OR x2<5) && (x3 equalTo 4) && (x4>7 OR x5<8)
```

Can be restated as:

```
(A || B) && E && (C || D)
```

Then restated by converting CNF to DNF ([cool tool by wolfram.alpha here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A%20%7C%7C%20B%29%20%26%20E%20%26%20%28C%20%7C%7C%20D%29))

```
(A && C && E) || (A && D && E) || (B && C && E) || (B && D && E)
```

Then restate as queries:

```
var q0=new Parse.Query("Player");
q0.greaterThan("x1", 2);
q0.greaterThan("x4", 7);
q0.equalTo("x3", 4);

var q1=new Parse.Query("Player");
q1.greaterThan("x1", 2);
q1.lessThan("x5", 8);
q1.equalTo("x3", 4);

var q2=new Parse.Query("Player");
q2.lessThan("x2", 5);
q2.greaterThan("x4", 7);
q2.equalTo("x3", 4);

var q3=new Parse.Query("Player");
q3.lessThan("x2", 5);
q3.lessThan("x5", 8);
q3.equalTo("x3", 4);

// notice the square braces.  the param to or is an array
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or([q0, q1, q2, q3]);
```